# Heap's Algorithm producing the same permutation twice

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation, heaps-algorithm

I am currently implementing Heaps's Algorithm in Python, but my current solution is returning some of the permutations twice.

```
def generate(startingIndex, alist):
    if startingIndex == 1:
        print(alist)
    else:
        for i in range(0, len(alist)):
            generate(startingIndex - 1, alist)
            if i % 2 == 1:
                alist[0], alist[startingIndex - 1] = alist[startingIndex - 1], alist[0]
            else:
                alist[i], alist[startingIndex - 1] = alist[startingIndex - 1], alist[i]

generate(3, ["a", "b", "c"])
```

This code produces the following results:

```
['a', 'b', 'c'] #this will be repeated
['b', 'a', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c'] #here
['b', 'c', 'a'] #this will be repeated
['c', 'b', 'a']
['b', 'c', 'a'] #here
['c', 'a', 'b'] #this will be repeated
['a', 'c', 'b'] 
['c', 'a', 'b'] #here
```

Since I do not want repeated results,

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried debugging yet? Try to perform your algorithm on a small example with pen and paper.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Heap's Algoritm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm), your loop should be iterating over `startingIndex` and not the length of the list.

You should also make the same recursive call after the `for` loop, and not just at the beginning of it.

This fixed version works for your example:

```
def generate(startingIndex, alist):
    if startingIndex == 1:
        print(alist)
    else:
        for i in range(startingIndex - 1):
            generate(startingIndex - 1, alist)
            if i % 2 == 1:
                alist[0], alist[startingIndex - 1] = alist[startingIndex - 1], alist[0]
            else:
                alist[i], alist[startingIndex - 1] = alist[startingIndex - 1], alist[i]
        generate(startingIndex - 1, alist)

generate(3, ['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Comment: @Chameera Wikipedia's definition of permutations is for sets, not lists, so it's hard to tell what you mean by this. Yes, it will have repetitions, but that's because the original list has repetitions (which is impossible for a set, since by definition a set doesn't contain repeated elements). Heap's Algorithm, as far as my understanding goes, doesn't deal with that.